# mail sent by bash shell, but not received

Tags: bash, email, mutt

Mail sent by bash with return code 0, but not received (I checked the 
target mail box for a few hours).

The command shell is:

```
echo "BodyOfMail" | mutt -a 1.png -s "AttachSuccess" -- lichunyu@xiaomi.com
```

Nevertheless, when I change the target email to xxx@qq.com, the mail 
can be received. i.e. :

```
echo "BodyOfMail" | mutt -a 1.png -s "AttachSuccess" -- coxfilur_2005@qq.com
```

The mail can be received.

I ever suspected that the png attachment may be the cause, so I removed it,
but still, I get the same result(xxx@xiaomi.com fail, xxx@qq.com OK).

In both of the cases, I tested the returned code by `$?`, and
both 0(which means success certainly).

Where is the problem, How can I solve it?
If there is something wrong the domain xiaomi.com, How do I know it?

Comment: My immediate suspicion is that it's something along the lines of not having the DNS PTR record for the FQDN your MTA claims to be, which is something many but not all MTAs check to exclude spam cannons. I think this is a question for [Superuser](https://superuser.com/), though.

Comment: I manually send the same content (title body and attached file) to lichunyu@xiaomi.com, and succeeded.  What is the difference between the two ways( manual and auto(mutt of bash))?  It seems it is not a spam-reason.